# ValueError: time data '2020-04-23T13:03:49.911533+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to fix an error that keeps popping up for some scripts I built. What I'm basically doing is retrieving some data from a Postgres database which includes a timestamptz field.

When I process that data, I sometimes get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-04-23T13:03:49.911533+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

The code where it happens:

```
last_seen_at_date = datetime.strptime(dict['last_seen_at'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').date()
```

What I don't understand is how this can happen.
When I copy paste this string and use it as a variable then convert it to a date, it works perfectly.

**Edit: Realized that this is working well on my Mac but not on my severs running on Ubuntu. Not sure how to fix this.**

Any idea on what's happening?

Thank you,

Comment: you could check if `dateutil`'s [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#parse-examples) works out for you

Answer (score 0):

> '2020-04-23T13:03:49.911533+00:00'

That does looks like ISO 8601 format, so it should work with [datetime.datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). I did test it using Python 3.7.3 and it seems to work correctly:

```
import datetime
dt_str ='2020-04-23T13:03:49.911533+00:00'
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dt_str)
print(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)
```

Output:

```
2020 4 23 13 3 49
```

Can you test it in your code?

Comment: Thanks @daweo !
Realized that this is working well on my Mac but not on my severs running on Ubuntu. Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue using an existing answer.
It's a problem with the different version of Python running on my servers.

[Datetime strptime issue with a timezone offset with colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268458/datetime-strptime-issue-with-a-timezone-offset-with-colons)